# jQuery hide url on last section

Tags: jquery, hide, footer, fullpage.js

I tried lot of solutions, but still can`t figure out how to do it. Im using fullpage.js and have fixed footer. "Fullpage.js" let you create a page with sections. You can scrool from section1 to section2, section2 -> section3 and etc... And all sections have fixed footer. I need hide footer on last section(page), but show on all other sections.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var len = $('.section').length;
    $('.section').each(function(index, element) {
        if (index == len - 1) {
        $('#footer').hide();
        } else {
         $('#footer').show();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Anybody could help me? How to hide #footer on the last section. Show in all sections but hide when person scrool on last section.

Best regards, thanks

Comment: What is the `footer` length ? one footer for all sections or each section have own footer?

Comment: Hey, its about 50px. And one footer for all sections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use Fullpage.js events to do that :

```
//Get the last section index
//Add 1 because index starts from 0 in jquery
var lastIndex = $('.section').last().index() + 1;

$('#fullpage').fullpage({
    //... your options are here ...
    onLeave: function (index, direction) {
        if (index == lastIndex) {
            $('#footer').fadeIn();
        }
    },
    afterLoad: function(anchorLink, index) {
        if (index == lastIndex) {
            $('#footer').fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```

So suppose your footer is $('#footer'), it will fade in or fade out when you leave or load the last section.

More info here : https://github.com/alvarotrigo/fullPage.js#onleave-index-nextindex-direction